# How many EECUs does Google Earth Engine task consume?

Tags: google-earth-engine

When computing anything in GEE, each operation consumes an amount of time for it.

It is called EECUs (Earth Engine Computing Units, if I'm not wrong).

Is there a way to extract, or logs, or info that describes this information i.e. how much EECUs some task spent?

Comment: Not yet.  Exposing this is on the roadmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the meanwhile this has became available through [`OperationMetadata`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/reference/rest/Shared.Types/OperationMetadata), in the field `batchEecuUsageSeconds`:

> **batchEecuUsageSeconds** **number**
>
> The amount of batch Earth Engine Compute Units (EECU) consumed when the operation is completed. The units are EECU*seconds.

For example, in Python, `ee.data.listOperations()` would return something like the following for a completed task:

```
[{'name': 'projects/earthengine-legacy/operations/YOURTASKID',
  'metadata': {'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.earthengine.v1alpha.OperationMetadata',
   'state': 'SUCCEEDED',
   'description': 'Exporting DATA.',
   'createTime': '2022-12-29T18:14:47.545860Z',
   'updateTime': '2022-12-29T18:17:21.017568Z',
   'startTime': '2022-12-29T18:14:54.753262Z',
   'endTime': '2022-12-29T18:17:21.017568Z',
   'type': 'EXPORT_IMAGE',
   'destinationUris': ['https://drive.google.com/#folders/YOURFOLDER'],
   'attempt': 1,
   'progress': 1,
   'stages': [{'displayName': 'Create Local Files',
     'completeWorkUnits': 1,
     'totalWorkUnits': '1',
     'description': 'Computation and writing of temporary files.'},
    {'displayName': 'Write Files to Destination',
     'completeWorkUnits': 1,
     'totalWorkUnits': '1',
     'description': 'Uploading of files to the export destination.'}],
   'batchEecuUsageSeconds': 20.32196617126465},
  'done': True,
  'response': {'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Empty'}}]
```

and `ee.data.getTaskStatus()` would have the same info but the dict key is now named `batch_eecu_usage_seconds`:

```
[{'state': 'COMPLETED',
  'description': 'Exporting DATA.',
  'creation_timestamp_ms': 1672337687545,
  'update_timestamp_ms': 1672337841017,
  'start_timestamp_ms': 1672337694753,
  'task_type': 'EXPORT_IMAGE',
  'destination_uris': ['https://drive.google.com/#folders/YOURFOLDER'],
  'attempt': 1,
  'batch_eecu_usage_seconds': 20.32196617126465,
  'id': 'YOURTASKID',
  'name': 'projects/earthengine-legacy/operations/YOURTASKID'}]
```

Comment: Actually, this feature has been launched months after my question. Thanks for your response. Rgds.

Answer (score 0):

Next to run, there is an diamond, click 'run with profiler'. It opens up a new tab next to tasks with EECU and other computation metrics:
[image]